# Question about the proof of Sobolev Embedding $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am reading *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, by Haim Brezis.

Corollary $9.13$ says (Among other results)

> For $m \geq 1, \quad W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) \qquad \text{if} \ \frac{1}{p} < \frac{m}{n} \qquad (*)$

And the proof says:

> The result can be obtained by repeated applications of Morrey's Theorem, which precisely says:
>
> If $p >n$ then $\quad W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n) $

I haven't been able to show the Embedding $(*)$ by "aplicating Morrey's theorem", because I cannot conclude that $p>n$.

For example, if $m=3, n=3$ and $p=2$, then we have $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{2} < \frac{3}{3}= \frac{m}{n}$. $(*)$ says we have the embedding: $$W^{3,2}(\mathbb{R}^3) \hookrightarrow L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$$

But definitely we cannot apply (At least trivially) Morrey's theorem because $ 2  \ngtr 3$.  We would need to conclude first that for $u \in W^{3,2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ then $u \in W^{1,\tilde{p}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for a $\tilde{p} >3$.

Comment: If you could show it when $p>n$, then you can perform in the same way by using Theorem 9.9 and Corollary 9.11, respectively, instead of the Morrey inequality.

Comment: @ACV Could you please explain a little bit more your reasoning? The main problem is that I cannot conclude $p >n$ You mean trying to conclude using the embeddings for $n<p$ and $n=p$?

Comment: You don't need $p>n$ but you must divide your proof in three the three cases: $p<n,\ p=n$ and $p>n$, and you got to use Theorem 9.9, Corollary 9.11 and the Morrey inequality in those respective cases.

Comment: @ACV I don't know how to do it. Let's say, supposing $\frac{1}{p} < \frac{m}{n}$, that $p=n$, then we can conclude that every derivative is in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $q \in [n, \infty]$. Then what?

Comment: @ACV Okay, so... If $u \in W^{m,p} $ and $p=n$ we can conclude $W^{m,p} \subset ... \subset W^{1,p} \subset L^q$ for $q \in [n, \infty]$. This means $Du, ..., D^{m-1}u \in W^{1,p} \subset L^q$ and thus we can conclude $u \in W^{1,q}$ for $q \in [n, \infty]$. We can now apply Morrey's theorem. Right?

Comment: @ACV I haven't been able to show it for the case $p <n$

Comment: @ACV $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{3}{3}$ and $p=2 < n=3$.

Answer (score 2):

I will consider $m=2$ (the general case follows by induction, with a similar argument).

Suppose that $\frac{1}{p}<\frac{2}{n}$. There are three cases:

**Case $\boldsymbol{p>n}$.** In this case, it follows from Theorem 9.12 that
$$W^{2,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,p}\hookrightarrow L^\infty.$$

**Case $\boldsymbol{p=n}$.** Take $f\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$. Then, $f,f_{x_i}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Since $p=n$, it follows from Corollary 9.11 that
$$\|f\|_{q}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{2,p}}\quad\text{and}\quad \|f_{x_i}\|_{q}\leq C\|f_{x_i}\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{2,p}}$$
for all $q\in[p,\infty)$. Therefore,
$$W^{2,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,q},\quad\forall\ q\in[p,\infty).$$
Taking $q>n$, it follows from  Theorem 9.12 that
$$W^{2,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,q}\hookrightarrow L^\infty.$$

**Case $\boldsymbol{p<n}$.** Take $f\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$. Then, $f,f_{x_i}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Since $p<n$, it follows from Corollary 9.10 that
$$\|f\|_{q}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{2,p}}\quad\text{and}\quad \|f_{x_i}\|_{q}\leq C\|f_{x_i}\|_{W^{1,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{2,p}}$$
for all $q\in[p,p^*]$, where $p^*=\frac{np}{n-p}>2p$. Therefore,
$$W^{2,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,q},\quad\forall\ q\in[p,p^*].$$
On the other hand, since $2p>n$, it follows from Theorem 9.12 that
$$W^{1,2p}\hookrightarrow L^\infty.$$
Taking $q=2p\in[p,p^*]$, we conclude that
$$W^{2,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,q}=W^{1,2p}\hookrightarrow L^\infty.$$